# IndustrialCraft machines not receiving power

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have a nuclear reactor hooked up to an MFSU, which then goes through MV and LV transformers to reach machines like compressors and macerators. It all worked fine up until I placed a mass fabricator on the output wire of the MFSU. Suddenly, all my machines stopped getting power, even when I removed the mass fabricator. I checked all the connections, but it should all be working fine. My quarry (which is connected to the HV output of the MFSU) is still getting power and working normally. I have roughly 5000000 EU in the MFSU, and even if I switch on my nuke it still does not power the machines. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you checked the output/input side on the transformers? Maybe they are facing the wrong way.

Comment: @Balen nope, like i said, the machines worked fine until the mass fabricator was added - the transformers did not change

Comment: I have sometimes noticed that for whatever reason the connector blocks (conduit conductive pipe, what have you..) "die" for lack of a better term. So I would have to break and replace. Sometimes one block. Others the whole line. Hope that's the issue. As it's a simple enough fix, heh heh.

Comment: @Bob I tried breaking/replacing all my glass fibre cable and something really weird has started happening. The machines get a tiny amount of power when i connect them again, and if i send s redstone pulse to my centrifuge extractor it starts to work for a very short period of time. They all then lost all their power. And I still have 5000000 EU in my MFSU, and i even tried disconnecting my quarry thinking it might be eating all my power, but to no avail

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes glass Fibre can be finicky.  I would suggest trouble shooting the line. Go two blocks of Fibre away from the mfsu. Then put something that should be able to accept power. What I suspect is happening is that some little short is occurring somewhere. Which would be a bug. As I assume glass Fibre should function like conduit.  Also it seems like there might be a problem with the transformers. As it is outputting power.   Still curious as to why it happened only after having the mass fabricator added.

Comment: ...my last suggestion. Perhaps the mass fab is just too efficient at taking and using power. I barely use that mod set. But is there a way for you to throttle the power being sent to the fabricator. The way you can set the output on Redstone cells? As that could provide a choke. Allowing power to the other machines.

Comment: @Bob I removed the fabricator and it's still bugged. Also I'm in tekkit classic so there's no redstone conduits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting a brand new world, a total fluke left me with the solution. In my new world, I had placed a lever next to a redstone engine, but on top of an LV transformer. As it turns out, when you apply a redstone current to a transformer, it prevents the flow of electricity. Sure enough, when I loaded my old world, I found a lever on a centrifuge extractor (which was on top of the LV transformer) and was therefore preventing the flow of electricity.